# Run roxygen on package installation

Tags: r, roxygen

I work on an R package that now uses Roxygen for the documentation. If users want to install a new version of the package (not on CRAN, just GitHub), they will have to do

```
git pull
```

and then in an R session

```
devtools::document()
install.packages('.', repo = NULL)
```

Roxygen introduces another step which is not obvious to R users. Is there some way that we can add the `devtools::document()` step into the installation/compilation step?

Comment: This has been discussed many times in many places. Just commit your compiled docs to git.

Comment: I don't like having generated files in git, these lead to needless merge conflicts. Were these discussions here on Stack Overflow or elsewhere?

Comment: Many threads on the devtools issue page: e.g. https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/397